# Implementing Counting Semaphore using test&set without disabling interrupts

Tags: process, synchronization, semaphore

I am trying to implement Counting semaphore using Test&Set.How can I solve the problem of deadlock in this code without disabling interrupts? Is it the case that no other solution is possible?

```
void wait(semaphore *s){

while(test_and_set(&lock_wait)):
s->val--;
if(s->val<0){
    s->queue.enque(This_process);
    block();
  }
  lock_wait = false;
}
void signal(semaphore *s)
{
  while(test_and_set(&lock_signal));
  s->val++;
  if(s->val <= 0)
  {
    process p = s->queue.dequeue();
    wakeup(p);
  }
  lock_signal = false;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please comment your code. And one more thing what do you got as output while implementing ? Add the output here, also ,bro !

While it is true that turning interrupts off on one processor is insufficient to guarantee atomic memory access in a multiprocessor system (because, as you mention, threads on other processors can still access shared resources), we turn interrupts off for part of the multiprocessor semaphore implementation because we do not want to be descheduled while we are doing a test and set.

If a thread holding the test and set is descheduled, no other threads can do anything with the semaphore (because its count is protected by that test and set) the thread was using while it's asleep (this is not good). In order to guarantee that this doesn't happen we'll turn interrupts on our processor off while using the test and set.